# Trying to connect Facebook Auth to Firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, facebook-login

I am trying to make Facebook auth in my app. In the emulator, it is logging in but in firebase not. I used only quick-start code from the tutorial and don't understand why it doesn't work. I figured out that it doesn't work on the step of

```
 mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
```

So it starts signInWithCredential but doesn't go threw to onComplete

Comment: Did you follow the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/facebook-login)?

Comment: @ADM sure the documentation on firebase and also FB. How i can figure out what can be the reason that on emulator i loged in but in firebase the user doesn't creates?